# How to filter different columns by different years?

Tags: r

I have 6 columns titled Year, Growth, Trade, Investment, Population and Inflation.

I want to filter Growth, and Inflation by Year > 1994. 
I want to filter Trade, Investent and Population by Year > 1993.

I want to do this in order to difference my data in order to achieve % Change.

Any help would be much appreciated?

I have tried:
    `OpennesstOTrade <-  summary(ireland, Year > 1993) %>% diff(ireland$OpennesstoTrade, lag = 1, differences = 1)`

Comment: It is not clear whether you need two subsets or not.  Please show a small reproducible example and expected output.  For the first case, perhaps `subset(df1, select = c("Growth", "Inflation"), Year > 1994)`

Comment: What did you tried? Please give a [mcve], i.e. edit your question: http://stackoverflow.com/posts/43667901/edit

Answer (score 0):

It should work if you use two filters?

I would try something like (dplyr)

```
df <- df %>%
  filter(Trade > 1993 & Investent >1993 & Population > 1993)%>% 
  filter(Year > 1994)
```

Comment: Would this work if you wanted to filter columns by different Years?

Comment: I may have misunderstood what you were asking for ... an small data sample would be helpful!